# Angular filter object and sub Object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/owtakr1a/6/

i have html like so

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model="name">
        <option value="company1">company1</option>
        <option value="company2">company2</option>
        <option value="company3">company3</option>
    </select>    

<li ng-repeat="(key,val) in info | filter:name "> 
        {{key}}::{{val}}
</li>
</div>
```

what i want is that when the user selects the company1 only its sub data should be displayed

the javascript is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.info={
    "company1":
        {"employee":"*2",
        "rooms":"*6",
        "vehicals":"3"},
    "company2":
        {"employee":"*2",
        "rooms":"*6"},
    "company3":
        {"employee":"*2",
        "rooms":"*6",
        "vehicals":"3"}
};

}
```

it works fine on single level object but i cant get it working on 2nd level

i tried the (key,val) in info but the filter doesn't seem to work then

Comment: can't filter an object... your data should be in array and set `company` as a property

Comment: How about just `ng-repeat="(key,val) in info[name]"`?

Comment: hey it worked..was focusing on filters but didn't look at the object..info[name]...But what i get is the values for company1 which are 2 6 3 i dont get the keys on them..how can i get the keys employee,rooms etc

Comment: sry my bad...problem solved....was focusing on filter..i didnt look at the object...info[name]....thanks